# Combine elements of a list of lists into a string

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to combine these 2 lists:

```
dots = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
spaces = [['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],
 ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ', '   ']]
```

I want every dot separeted by a space and turn them into string just like this:

```
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

I wrote this code but it only work for the first line:

```
lists = [a for b in zip(dots[0], spaces[0]) for a in b]
line = ''.join(liste)
```

I wanted to know how to loop in for every other sublist in these two lists.

Comment: Do the spaces go before or after the dots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know how to use `zip` to simultaneously iterate over two lists, so do that and create a list of strings containing a dot and space for each "row":

```
lines = [
          "".join(
              dot + space 
              for dot, space in zip(row_dots, row_spaces)
          )
          for row_dots, row_spaces in zip(dots, spaces) 
       ]
```

Then join the individual lines using the newline character `'\n'`.

```
output = "\n".join(lines)
print(output)

.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Of course, you can combine both into a single statement so that you don't need to create the list of lines:

```
output = "\n".join(
              "".join(
                  dot + space 
                  for dot, space in zip(row_dots, row_spaces)
              )
              for row_dots, row_spaces in zip(dots, spaces) 
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

You solved your problem for list, last thing you need is to iterate over every list in **dots** and **spaces**

```
result = []
for i in range(len(dots)):
    lists = [a for b in zip(dots[i], spaces[i]) for a in b]
    line = ''.join(lists)
    result.append(line)
```

Or just put it into your list comprehesion:

```
lists = [a for i in range(len(dots)) for b in zip(dots[i], spaces[i]) for a in b]
line = "".join(lists)
```